# I'm confused as about 2 things. Why ComponentWillUnmount & removeEventListener need to be called for this to work properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

so I have been surfing the web trying to figure out the point of compontWillUnmount just see know point of firing events when the component is gone, I don't get why this functionality (scroll event) doesn't work without it.

Please somebody help me understand

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class ScrollPos extends Component {

  state = {
    position: null
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('componentDidMount Fired')
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll)
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    console.log('comontWillUnmount fired')
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll)
  }

  handleScroll = (e) => {
    const scrollTop = window.scrollY;
    console.log(scrollTop)
    this.setState({
      position: scrollTop
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="spacer">
        <div className="yellow">
          {this.props.children(this.state.position)}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ScrollPos;
```

Comment: Could you re-phrase the question? Are you saying the events will get sent even after the component is removed?

Comment: I'm curious to know why window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll) needs to be put in the componentWillUnmount method for this to work properly

Comment: Ok and you are noticing that the events are not received in your “handleScroll” method, correct?

Comment: Like I thought all you need to do is just add the event listener to the window object. Why do you need to remove it for the scroll event to work.

Comment: @JohnBryant The Scroll event works without `componentWillUnmount` - https://jsfiddle.net/reactjs/69z2wepo/ - What are you expecting to happen? The `componentUnmount` "pattern" is there in order to clean up after yourself.

Comment: Really it works without componentWillUnmount? hold on one second let me try it out. Because i swear it didn't work without it.

Comment: Wow............... it does work without the componentWillUnmount as i thought it should no idea why i thought it wasn't working. Is there like a performance gain, or anything from removing it. Because I'm noticing a lot of people removing the listeners at componentWillUnmount.

Comment: @JohnBryant it helps avoiding memory leaks, you shouldn't keep listening to some value (invoking a function in other words with every scroll) when you don't need it

Answer (score 1):

In your `handleScroll` method, you are using `this` which is instance of your component. When component is unmounted (removed from the DOM) it gets destroyed. If you don't remove the listener, your method is still going to get called on window scroll (as `window` is still there).

You may guessed why is this bad. For a start, if you mount and unmount multiple components, each one of them will leak a listener (this leads to memory leaks as well). This leads to performance drop. In your specific case, leaked listeners will call `handleScroll` which is trying to call `this.setState` on `this` that doesn't exist anymore. I'm pretty sure React will handle this one gracefully, but you can imagine this can to errors which can break your whole application.

Hope that helps!